# Laravel Livewire pagination with bootstrap links not displaying

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel Livewire with bootstrap 4. I'm trying to use pagination but the links aren't displaying at the bottom of the table. I don't think the issue is in my blade file or in the livewire component itself, as I can see in the response that there's no pagination `links()` method available by doing this:

```
$x = User::paginate(5);
dd($x);
```

Which yields this result, and contains no reference to `links`

[image]

In my livewire component I'm including the trait: `use WithPagination;`, and I'm also including the `protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';` line as well.

At the bottom of my div just after the table element I have included:

`{{ $users->links() }}`

Everything I'm doing seems to be "by the book" in terms of what the docs say, but the links just don't display. It's limiting the number of rows on the page as well, just no links.

Comment: Have you tried `dd($x->links())`? It should return a View instance

Comment: @vozaldi good idea, I just did that and it does return an object of type `Illuminate\View\View`, so that seems to be working correctly.

Comment: I just figured it out, it was a naming error on my component, so totally my fault. ugh.

Answer (score 4):

On your Livewire component:

```
use Livewire\WithPagination;
```

Inside class use the trait:

```
use WithPagination;
```

Then set the pagination theme:

```
protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
```